# API mocking in cypress intercept

Tags: mocking, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am not able to intercept URL for API mocking, when there are multiple APIs that are appearing in console-> network tab

My requirement is as follows:

1. login a website, after getting the landing page,go to a particular web page, select multiple test cases check boxes
2. open console-> network tab , and click run
3. watch multiple APIs are coming
4. I selected one API URL among them. I want to mock this particular one.
   'GET'method , URL (say: `https://externalAPIurl`) are copied in the following code

```js
//verify landing page is reached
cy.contains("this is landing page").should("exist");

//after login open testcase page
cy.visit("https://example.com/testcases");

//go to test suite tab test suite
cy.get("#testsuiteid")
  .click();
 //click test suite name 
cy.contains("testsuitename").click();

// select all test cases 
cy.get(".testcasecheckbox")
  .click();

cy.intercept({ method: "GET",  url: "https://externalAPIurl" },
  { headers: { authorization: "AABBXXYY", } },
  { statusCode: 200,
    body: [
      {
        status: 200,
        result: true,
        combination: [  //same data...  ],
      },
    ],
  }
);

cy.get("#run_button").click();
})
```

I checked in postman, the URL, with Get method and Header-> Authorization key with proper Authorization key value (as collected from network console Headers) giving correct response, but the `cy.intercept` is throwing error

Whenever in a website we click a button, multiple external API s are visible in console-> network. If I take any one of them -> check the URL, method, header and getting the same response in postman as in the network console, I should be able to mock the same request URL.

I tried the same when one single API is appearing in network console. It was fine. But when I select one among multiple the result is an error.

I have included the header authorization, may be the format is wrong. But if I give or do not give the authorization, the result is the same error.

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: Are you taking into account get params when you fill the url field? From some time ago to match routes you need to be more accurate and add ** if there are more params

Comment: Have you added the intercept before the API request is sent by your app?

Comment: agoff I am getting a red line while execution, but there is no error message. That red line just shows a line number like 35, sometimes that line is just cy. wait(5000) , sometimes cy. contains("test suite name string").click(); 

veronica, can you please provide an example, thank you

jjhelguero my sequence is cy. intercept(..), after that the button which I will click to get the API to intercept. I think this sequence is correct

Answer (score 1):

The `cy.intercept()` cannot be placed at the end on the code, it will never catch requests that have already triggered.

It's not clear which action (visit, or one of the clicks) is the trigger so just make sure you put the intercept ***at the top***.

As for headers and other intercept details, the pattern you have looks invalid, there should only be a routeMatcher and routeHandler, but you have three objects.

The following is an approximation of what you need to do.

```js
cy.intercept(

  // routeMatcher
  { method: "GET",  url: "https://externalAPIurl" },

  // routeHandler
  { 
    headers: { authorization: "AABBXXYY" }, 
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      status: 200,
      result: true,
      combination: [  //same data...  ],
    }
  }
)

cy.contains("this is landing page").should("exist");

cy.visit("https://example.com/testcases");

cy.get("#testsuiteid").click();
cy.contains("testsuitename").click();
cy.get(".testcasecheckbox").click();

cy.get("#run_button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept a 'GET' and stub the response with predefined data. I would first use dev tools network tab to capture the api response you want. Copy the response and save as a json file in your fixture folder (you can edit this file as you see fit to fake the data how you wish). From there you can do the following:

```
cy.fixture('apiResponse.json').as('fixture data')
.then( (data) =>{
  const raw = JSON.stringify(data)
  cy.request( {
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'api url here',
    headers : {
      authorization : 'AABBXXYY',
    },
    body : raw
})
.then( (response) => {
  cy.log(response.body)
  expect(`Response.status = ${response.status}`).to.eq('Response.status = 200')
})
})
```